# How to run a m file in middle of simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, differential-equations

I am building a system of coupled differential equations in Simulink. For all the variables in flow diagram like B, C, V0 I have defined their values in the workspace. There is a variable D3 which varies with time (actually with the angular position). So, I have written a .m file which contains all possible values of D3 for different angular positions (like 0 to 30 degrees, 30 to 90, 90-360 etc) I just need to know how to link these values of D3 with the time that is used by Simulink to evaluate by model. Hope I am clear with the question.Below attached are Simulink model and .m file code images. Inside the if conditions of code image it should be just D3 not D3(th,1)

[This is simulink flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rt2BF.jpg)

[This is the m file code for a computing a variable D3 in simulink diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpXDT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options for blocks:

- [MATLAB Function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html)
- [Interpreted MATLAB Function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/interpretedmatlabfunction.html)
- [M-Code S-Function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/level2matlabsfunction.html)

Or, depending on exactly how your function is used, you could (during model initialization) create MATLAB variables (by calling your function) to create appropriate data for use in a [Look-up Table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/1dlookuptable.html)